# firebase-ui:3.1.0 build error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I use recyclerveiw in my android app,

I use firebase-ui:2.1.0 in my gradle,but I find that if my android is 6.0 or over,
my app will bug.

So I update my dependencies to firebase-ui:3.1.0.
(refer to [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) link )

But It happened this error message:
[image]

How could I solve this problam? plz

Comment: Why are you integrate firebase with .aar file ? Try to integrate with firebase directly from android studio. Tools -> Firebase..and follow the steps for that i will automatically add all the required compile files as well as google-json file,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Just make sure your

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

version is the same as

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Mine was different and changing just this solved the problem.